My website auto generate hundreds of URLs with the same pattern, and it affects my SEO, how can i stop that and delete them?
i bought an expired domain, and i noticed in google search console that their is +2500 craweled URLs that has the same pattern (ex : www.website.com/?3567hyvz7582zmo1041590_html)
and most of them lead to the home page, i noticed that it keeps generating more,
anyone knows how can i fix this or what is this problem called so i can search for solutions ?
(after buying the domain,i use wordpress for my website)




That looks like a hacked site to me at first glance. WordPress should not do that if it's configured properly. I would check Google's cached version of these urls in search console to see if they show some spammer's page when google crawls them.

Review all code on your site, run security and rookit scans, and configure your server to return 404 on any page that matches the patterns you are seeing.
